# Dynamic parameter for GetFile/ListFile processor - NiFi

Tags: hdfs, apache-nifi

My workflow is like below.

> ListenHTTP(i get a directory name here) --> SplitText -->
>   ExtractText(directory name added as attribute)

Now after this i will have to use that attribute directoryname and extract all the files in that local dir and put that into HDFS. I understand GetFile/ListFile could do this, but how do we provide a dynamic directory name to that processor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, both `GetFile` and `ListFile` are *source* processors, which means they do not accept an incoming flowfile. The general pattern is to configure these processors with a static **Input Directory** value and allow them to read from it and manage their state.

In this case, I believe you need to use `FetchFile`, which accepts an incoming flowfile and reads the file path provided. By default, the **File to Fetch** property is set to `${absolute.path}/${filename}`, which means it uses [Apache NiFi Expression Language](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html) to resolve the value of those two *attributes* on the incoming flowfile. You could pass that flowfile to an `ExecuteStreamCommand` processor first and perform an `ls` on the directory, then split the results into individual flowfiles with one filename per line, and process each of these through the `FetchFile`.

I understand this isn't the most concise way to perform the task. Two other suggestions would be:

1. [Open a Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:summary-panel) to request a processor which retrieves all of the files in a directory (at the time of incoming flowfile receipt) and requires an incoming flowfile to determine the directory.
2. Use an `ExecuteScript` processor. The processor would simply extract the attribute from the incoming flowfile and use Groovy/Ruby/Python/etc. facilities to retrieve the files from the directory, or perform the directory listing and pass individual flowfiles downstream to a `FetchFile` processor.

Comment: Thanks Andy I would have to create the workflow in a quick time. I would try option 2 and post my feedback.